# Why do I get this 'SensorNatAvailable' error? What is wrong?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

My Nokia Icon is developer unlocked running the Windows Phone 8.1 Preview.
I am just testing the HelloSensorApp from the Nokia site http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/sensorcore-sdk/quick-start.html

I build the application and deploy it to my device (Nokia Icon). When activated it comes up with the error.
"Failure:
 SenseNotAvailable" with a button to close the window.

This model is expected to support Lumia SensorCore.
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Nokia-SensorCore-Opens-Sensors-on-Lumia-Devices-to-Applications-435972.shtml besides other models.

Also, I am running Microsoft's Health and Wellness app on my Nokia Icon and it requires Lumia SensorCore support.
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-do-i-get-health-and-wellness-app-to.html

Looks like two things are to be in place for Lumia SensorCore to work:
Location
Motion Data
I just found out that Motion Data is not supported on Nokia Icon. There are two other models, one even a low cost device which has motion data.
The (Bing)Health and Wellness app just uses the 'Location' GPS Info

Comment: The user may not have agreed to the obscene terms of service. On Windows Phone, you have to agree to be data rapped before you can use the sensors. Related: [TA14-295A: Crypto Ransomware](http://linuxbox.org/pipermail/funsec/2014-October/028821.html) on the FunSec mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Lumia Icon phone does support Lumia SensorCore as well Motion Data, but requires Lumia Denim SW update on it. Check Settings/phone update/check for update and download Denim SW package.

Comment: Verizon finally upgraded Nokia icon OS to windows 8.1 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.0 does not support Machine Data in your settings. You need Windows 8.1 and like two days ago Verizon upgraded and now you have full access to sensor core.